# Converting a string into an List

Tags: java, string

Is there a not-so-messy way to convert a `String` `"[1,2,3]"` into a `List<Long>` ? I tried to find some good ways but most takes many steps

Comment: Your string is valid JSON, you could use Jackson's ObjectMapper to do it, but it seems like over kills

Comment: What ways have you tried? What do you consider "many" steps?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to parse that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A neat way to do it is

```
String s = "[1,2,3]"
s=s.sbustring(1,s.length-1);
List<Long> numLongs = new ArrayList<Long>();
for(String eachString: s.split(",")){
    try {
        numLongs.add(Long.parseLong(eachString))
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("failed to convert : "+s); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this is a JSON representation of an array, you can use any JSON api.

For instance using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson):

```
String s = "[1,2,3]";
long[] a = new ObjectMapper().reader(long[].class).readValue(s);
List<Long> l = new ObjectMapper().reader(List.class).readValue(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
String x = "[1,2,3]";
List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : x.substring(1,x.length()-1).split(",")) {
    myList.add(Long.valueOf(s));
}
```

or

```
String x = "[1,2,3]";
List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String s : x.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","").split(",")) {
    myList.add(Long.valueOf(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str= "[1,2,3]";
        String []arr=str.substring(1, str.length()-1).split(",");
        List<Long>list=new ArrayList<Long>();
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
           list.add(Long.parseLong(arr[i]));
       }
       System.out.println(list);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8

```
    String str = "1,2,3";
    String[] sp = str.split(",");
    List<String> listSt = Arrays.asList(sp);
    listSt.forEach(System.out::print);
    List<Long> listLong = listSt.stream().map( str1 -> Long.parseLong(str1)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    listLong.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Comment: Using `asList` isn't really necessary; `Arrays` has its own static `stream()` method, i.e. `Arrays.stream(sp).map...`